# in c# winform, How to keep a control always in the center bottom of a form when form's size changed?

Tags: c#, winforms

in c# winform, How to keep a control always in the center bottom of a form when form's size changed?

if I use DockStyle.Bottom, I can't set its width.

I tried it out. The following is the code, but I don't know why? It's mainly because I don't understand why the Left value will change when the Anchor. Bottom is set?

```
    public void Run()
    {
        Form form = new Form();
        form.Width = 600;
        form.Height = 600;

        Button btnOK = new Button();
        btnOK.Text = "OK";
        btnOK.Left = form.ClientSize.Width / 2 - btnOK.Width;
        btnOK.Top = 0;
        btnOK.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom;
        Button btnCancel = new Button();
        btnCancel.Text = "Cancel";
        btnCancel.Left = form.ClientSize.Width / 2;
        btnCancel.Top = 0;
        btnCancel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom;

        Panel panel = new Panel();
        panel.Height = btnOK.Height;
        panel.Width = form.ClientSize.Width;
        panel.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
        panel.Controls.Add(btnOK);
        panel.Controls.Add(btnCancel);

        form.Controls.Add(panel);
        form.Show();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try `Anchor.Bottom` ??

Comment: It's not clear what kind of behavior you're expecting. Isn't the Panel always at the Center-Bottom of the Form now? Why would you set its Width? To implement what kind of behavior instead of the current? Do you want to limit the width of the Panel to a minimum / maximum value? Leave space for other docked / anchored containers? Other?

Comment: Yes, exactly *how* is this not the behavior you said you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a TableLayoutPanel. You can Dock it to the Bottom or Anchor it to the Bottom, Left and Right. You would have one row then have a column with an absolute width for each control and one extra column on the left and another on the right with 50% width. Those two extra columns will take up half the empty space each, thus keeping the others in the middle.